# "Access is denied" when calling SQLServer from one app but not another

Tags: vb.net, sqlconnection

I wanted to make a little demo app, so I made a new project and linked-to a number of key files from our full version. One part of that code is:

```
    Dim pSqlClientFactory As SqlClientFactory = SqlClientFactory.Instance
    Cnn = pSqlClientFactory.CreateConnection()
    DBComm = pSqlClientFactory.CreateCommand()
    Cnn.ConnectionString = ConStr
    Cnn.Open()
    DBComm.Connection = Cnn
```

`Cnn` and `DBComm` are `ByRef`s that get passed back to the enclosing code so they can call more commands on it.

In the original program, all of this code runs perfectly and the queries return almost instantly. In the new app, it times out on `Cnn.Open()` with an outer error about network problems, and an inner error of "Access is denied". I am using the same connection string (I c&ped from the console and checked char for char), SPPI security, and SQL Admin works perfectly.

As I said, the code is not just the same, it's identical. Just to be sure I added a comment in one to ensure it showed up in the other - it did. Both are also running on the same version of .Net, 3.5.1. I checked references, and nothing is missing, neither app generates even a single warning. I even changed the project name thinking the space I stupidly used might be the problem. Nope.

I assume I am missing some little thing, but any ideas what that might be?

**UPDATE:** the clients and server are on the same machine, the server is SQLExpress 2014. SSMS runs perfectly using Windows Authentication, which is what the clients use too.

Comment: Have you gone through these: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/328306

Comment: I have - those are all generic and cannot explain why one app works and the other doesn't (barring constr differences, but there are none).

Comment: You're running both applications from the same machine and connecting to the same server, right? Have you tried connecting to the server using SSMS ?

Comment: SSMS works perfectly.

Comment: Copied it to a USB, ran it on another machine, works fine. Bizarre!

Comment: Indeed. I assume SQL Server has tracing you can turn on for the client side that may assist in narrowing down the issue.

Comment: Question: is it possible the user info is different between the two projects? I'm using SPPI, but perhaps the app settings change this somehow?

Comment: no, as far as you're not changing the current user or impersonating another user.

Comment: Well apparently it was the connection string. In spite of the debugger saying it was identical, when I simply saved the text file containing the string back into the demo app's build folder, it immediately worked. I am assuming it was character coding or something like that, because Excel said =(A1,B1) was TRUE. Bizarre!